# Warning: Fixture creation for "catalog_items" failed " SQLSTATE[42S01]

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit, cakephp-3.0, fixtures

This is error, which I have got. Let me know what is root cause of it.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`Proficiency`.`t_catalog_item_recommendations`, CONSTRAINT `fk_t_catalog_item_recommendations_catalog_item_id` FOREIGN KEY (`catalog_item_id`) REFERENCES `Proficiency`.`t_catalog_items` (`id`))

Whenever i execute my testscripts it gives this message:

> Warning: Fixture creation for "catalog_items" failed "SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 't_catalog_items' already exists" in /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeTestFixture.php on line 244 Call Stack: 0.0018 262208 1. {main}() /var/www/html/app/webroot/test.php:0 0.1119 1133560 2. CakeTestSuiteDispatcher::run() /var/www/html/app/webroot/test.php:97 0.1120 1133968 3. CakeTestSuiteDispatcher->dispatch() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php:113 0.1205 1278304 4. CakeTestSuiteDispatcher->_runTestCase() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php:96 0.1314 1320376 5. CakeTestSuiteCommand->run() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php:253 0.1930 2144664 6. CakeTestRunner->doRun() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteCommand.php:96 0.2285 2481368 7. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestRunner.php:60 0.2334 2521736 8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:350 0.2538 2770160 9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:749 0.2538 2770288 10. CakeTestCase->run() /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:779 0.2538 2770512 11. CakeFixtureManager->load() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestCase.php:80 0.2541 2772984 12. CakeFixtureManager->_setupTable() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeFixtureManager.php:234 0.2572 2784752 13. CakeTestFixture->create() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeFixtureManager.php:206 0.4597 2824904 14. trigger_error() /var/www/html/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeTestFixture.php:244

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html) says:

> TRUNCATE cannot be used on a table that has foreign-key references from other tables, unless all such tables are also truncated in the same command.

So that's what you'll have to do.